# How do I resolve linker error LNK2019 while including "zlib" in my Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, linker-errors

I got the precompiled "lib" and "dll" from here: http://zlib.net/zlib128-dll.zip

I am compiling my project in x64.

I added directory into `"Additional Include Directories"`

I added the "zdll.lib"  to `Linker -> Additional Dependencies`.

I added the library directory to `Linker -> Additional Library Directories`.

I also added the Post-Build Event `"xcopy ..\oem\zlib\*.dll "$(TargetDir)"`

But I still get the Linker error:

```
: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflateInit_ referenced in function
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You *don't* need to copy zlib dll's to the TargetDirectory. It is used only in build time.  Did you try to link with /VERBOSE? Is zlib.lib shown there?

Comment: @OfekShilon: Are you sure the DLLs are used during **build time**? That would really be extraordinary.

Answer (score 0):

IS that a 32-bit dll? If so, you'll have to obtain, or build your own, 64-bit version.

The linker error happens with the lib file, if you have the right headers it'll compile, if you have the right lib, it'll link, if you have the right dll, it'll run.